# rake db:create vs rake db:create:all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

What is the difference between `rake db:create` and `rake db:create:all`? 
 
Both are equally used in order to create a database for a Rails application. 
The most exhaustive information on rake for Rails I could find is at [tutorialpoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-and-rake.htm) but the above commands are missing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- `rake db:create:all` creates all the databases for the application (which are defined in `database.yml`)
- `rake db:create` creates the database for the current `RAILS_ENV` environment. If `RAILS_ENV` is not specified it defaults to the development and test databases.

FYI: http://jacopretorius.net/2014/02/all-rails-db-rake-tasks-and-what-they-do.html

Answer (score 2):

One creates the DB for the current environment.

One creates the DB for *all* environments.

Answer (score 2):

If you run `rake -T | grep db`, you will see :

```
rake db:create 
# Creates the database from DATABASE_URL or config/database.yml for the current RAILS_ENV
# (use db:create:all to create all databases in the config)
```